# Interface implementation idioms

Tags: c++, performance, interface, cross-platform, idioms

I'm trying to write cross-platform library which will be used on *embed system (performance is very important)*.
I used to check **PIMPL idiom**, which looks fine, but i'am little a bit scared of dynamic object allocation which is kind a heavy operation (where i will allocate lots of classes).
Also i tried to attach implementation files in IDE depending on target system.
By this trick I think that I got very well performance but decreased code clarity, and had to use preprocessor to define in class system dependent variables.
**Can somebody tell me which of above idioms is best in my case, or if there is better one, tell name of it.**
Thanks.

Comment: Having a system with tight resources, you should avoid abstractions and focus on modelling data. I  guess a PIMPLE will do no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIMPL idiom is mainly used for its role as a *compilation firewall*.

If class `A` is implemented using the pimpl idiom (so that there is e.g. `A` and `A_impl`), then clients of `A` do not need to see the definition of `A_impl` or include the header files for any of the private variables or other implementation details of it.

If you don't actually care about this compilation firewall and are more concerned about dynamic allocation, then a 'faster' idiom you could use is *static polymorphism*, based on CRTP.

When you use CRTP, you can get the same methods to appear in a variety of different subclasses, without incurring the cost of virtual dispatch. A downside though is that, most of the functions that use the subclasses need to be template functions, so it results in a lot of extra code generation. That's the fundamental trade-off between static polymorphism and dynamic polymorphism (via e.g. virtual dispatch).

I'm not entirely sure how common it is to use CRTP for this in embedded systems -- it still might be more common to use pimpl or virtual dispatch because of the code generation issues. YMMV.

Comment: You do not need CRTP for static polymorphism.

Comment: That's true, and I don't think I implied otherwise. To make an interface though it seems like a quite appropriate thing to mention.